# Ruby comparing values in hashes and returning the same structure

Tags: ruby

I have 2 hashes like so:

```
stored_hash = {
   :name    => "hash_1",
   :version => "1.0",
   :values  => {
     :value_1 => "some_value",
     :value_2 => "some_other_value",
     :value_3 => "a_new_value",
     ...
     :value_x => "some_x_value"
   }
}

compare_hash = {
  :name    => "hash_2",
  :version => "2.0",
  :values  => {
    :different_1 => "some_value",
    :different_2 => "some_other_value",
    :different_3 => "a_new_value",
    ...
    :different_x => "some_x_value"
  }
}
```

I find the common values in the `:values` key of both the hashes like this :

```
same_values = hash[:values].values & compared_hash[:values].values
```

And once I get it, I want to return a new hash similar to 'stored_hash', but with the `:values` of it containing the same_values I found before.

For example, if both hashes have `"some_value"`, `"some_other_value"`, `"a_new_value"`, my new hash should look like :

```
new_hash = {
  :name    => "hash_1",
  :version => "1.0",
  :values  => {
    :value_1 => "some_value",
    :value_2 => "some_other_value",
    :value_3 => "a_new_value"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are `hash` and `compared_hash`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
stored_hash = {
   :name    => "hash_1",
   :version => "1.0",
   :values  => {
     :value_1 => "some_value",
     :value_2 => "some_other_value",
     :value_3 => "a_new_value",
     :value_x => "some_a_value"
   }
}

compare_hash = {
  :name    => "hash_2",
  :version => "2.0",
  :values  => {
    :different_1 => "some_value",
    :different_2 => "some_other_value",
    :different_3 => "a_new_value",
    :different_x => "some_b_value"
  }
}

common_values = compare_hash[:values].values & stored_hash[:values].values
new_hash = stored_hash.dup
new_hash[:values] = {}
common_values.each_with_index do |value, index |
    new_hash[:values]["value_#{index+1}".to_sym] = value
end
new_hash
# => new_hash = {
#      :name    => "hash_1",
#      :version => "1.0",
#      :values  => {
#      :value_1 => "some_value",
#      :value_2 => "some_other_value",
#      :value_3 => "a_new_value"
#      }
#   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could obtain your desired result.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def make_new_hash(stored_hash, compare_hash)
  new_hash = stored_hash.dup
  compare_values =
    (stored_hash[:values].values & compare_hash[:values].values).to_set
  values_hash = new_hash[:values]
  keys_to_keep = values_hash.keys.select { |k|
    compare_values.include?(values_hash[k])}
  new_hash[:values] =
    Hash[keys_to_keep.zip(values_hash.values_at(*keys_to_keep))]
  new_hash
end
```

**Example**

```
stored_hash = {
   :name    => "hash_1",
   :version => "1.0",
   :values  => {
     :value_1 => "some_value",
     :value_2 => "some_other_value",
     :value_3 => "a_new_value",
     :value_x => "some_x_value"
   }
}

compare_hash = {
  :name    => "hash_2",
  :version => "2.0",
  :values  => {
    :different_1 => "some_value",
    :different_2 => "a_new_value",
    :different_3 => "some_strange_value",
    :different_x => "some_x_value"
  }
}
```

Note that I've made a small change in `stored_hash` from that given in the question.

```
make_new_hash(stored_hash, compare_hash)
  #=> {:name=>"hash_1", :version=>"1.0",
  #    :values=>{:value_1=>"some_value", :value_3=>"a_new_value",
  #    :value_x=>"some_x_value"}}
```

**Explanation**

Create a copy of `stored_hash`:

```
new_hash = stored_hash.dup
  #=> {:name=>"hash_1", :version=>"1.0",
  #    :values=>{:value_1=>"some_value",
  #              :value_2=>"some_other_value",
  #              :value_3=>"a_new_value",
  #              :value_x=>"some_x_value"}}
```

We only want to keep a key `k` of `new_hash[:values]` if `new_hash[:values][k]` is one of the values in both the hash `stored_hash[:values]` and the hash `compare_hash[:values]`, so we obtain those values:

```
compare_values =
  (stored_hash[:values].values & compare_hash[:values].values).to_set
  # => #<Set: {"some_value", "a_new_value", "some_x_value"}>
```

I chose to save them in a set both to speed lookup and to obtain unique values. They could alternatively be saved to array like so:

```
(stored_hash[:values].values & compare_hash[:values].values).uniq
  #=> ["some_value", "a_new_value", "some_x_value"]
```

The code that follows is the same if an array is used rather than a set.

To simpify, let's create a variable:

```
values_hash = new_hash[:values]
  #=> {:value_1=>"some_value", :value_2=>"some_other_value",
  #    :value_3=>"a_new_value", :value_x=>"some_x_value"}
```

Next determine the keys of `New_hash[:values]` we wish to keep:

```
keys_to_keep = values_hash.keys.select { |k|
  compare_values.include?(values_hash[k])}
  #=> [:value_1, :value_3, :value_x]
```

All keys other than `:value_2` are kept. That key is not kept because `comparative_hash[:values]` does not have a value `"some_other_value"`.

We can now construct the updated value of `new_hash[:values]`:

```
new_hash[:values] =
  Hash[keys_to_keep.zip(values_hash.values_at(*keys_to_keep))]
  #=> {:value_1=>"some_value", :value_3=>"a_new_value",
  #    :value_x=>"some_x_value"}
```

Lastly, we return `new_hash`:

```
new_hash
  #=> {:name=>"hash_1", :version=>"1.0",
  #    :values=>{:value_1=>"some_value", :value_3=>"a_new_value",
  #    :value_x=>"some_x_value"}}
```

Let's confirm that `stored_hash` will not be changed when a value of `new_hash[:values]` is changed:

```
new_hash[:values][:value_1] = 'cat'
new_hash
  #=> {:name=>"hash_1", :version=>"1.0",
  #    :values=>{:value_1=>"cat", :value_3=>"a_new_value",
  #    :value_x=>"some_x_value"}} 
stored_hash
  #=> {:name=>"hash_1", :version=>"1.0",
  #    :values=>{:value_1=>"some_value", :value_2=>"some_other_value",
  #    :value_3=>"a_new_value", :value_x=>"some_x_value"}}
```